# update setState with string of the key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a react component that contains input boxes. I want to make sure that the input boxes are not empty.

On `componentDidMount` I run the following function:

`this.validateInputLength(this.state.first_name, 'firstNameValid');`

as you can see I pass in the value of `this.state.first_name` and the string `'firstNameValid'`.

The problem is that `'firstNameValid'` is not setting the state of the component. [I was under the impression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal) that I could pass the key of the state object in as a string and it would update, however this does not appear to be working.

See complete code below for more context.

```js
class Test extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
      firstNameValid: true,
      lastNameValid: true
    };
  
    this.validateInputLength = this.validateInputLength.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    this.validateInputLength(this.state.first_name, 'firstNameValid');
    this.validateInputLength(this.state.last_name, 'lastNameValid');

  }


  validateInputLength(value, inputType) {

    if (value.length <= 0) {

      this.setState({
        inputType: false
      });

    } else {

      this.setState({
        inputType: true
      });

    }
  }

  render() {
    ........
  }
}
```

Comment: You need square brackets around `inputType` like this `this.setState({ [inputType]: true })`

Comment: I was going to add an answer before it was marked as duplicate, but here is a better way to write that function:

`validateInputLength(value, inputType) {
  this.setState({
    [inputType]: value.length > 0
  })
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it in square brackets to achieve what you're after.

```js
var testing = "testable";

var test = {
 [testing]: "value in [testing]"
};

document.getElementById("value").innerText = test.testable;
```

```html
<p id="value"></p>
```